# Can't ping my computer - "Transmit failed. General failure."

Tags: windows, networking, ping

I am having an issue with my computer.  My IIS services are not working.

I have narrowed it down to the fact that my computer cannot find itself via its name.

I try pinging my computer by its name and I get this:

C:\Users\18773>ping MyComputerNameHere

```
Pinging MyComputerNameHere [::1] with 32 bytes of data:
PING: transmit failed. General failure.
PING: transmit failed. General failure.
PING: transmit failed. General failure.
PING: transmit failed. General failure.

Ping statistics for ::1:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),
```

I tried having someone else ping my machine and it works fine for them.

Any ideas?

Comment: when you ping over a network using a computer name, you are using WINS. Can you ping your computer by IP address? if so, then for some reason WINS translation is failing, if not, then something is going on with your network connection, but that is a place to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that my computer somehow has decided that my local connection is IP v6.

Not sure why.  All other pinging uses v4.  Anyway, once I enabled v6 on my network card, it started working again (though it shows v6 IP addresses)

Wish I knew how to tell it to use IP v4 again, but at least it is working.

Answer (score 2):

Since Vista and Server 2008, Windows prefers IPv6 whenever possible. In your case, Windows did prefer to lookup the AAAA record instead of the corresponding A record. Therefore, the host did ping `::1` and not `127.0.0.1` or any other IPv4 address.

How to disable the preference of IPv6: [IPv4 vs IPv6 priority in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/436574/ipv4-vs-ipv6-priority-in-windows-7) at superuser.com.

There is a packaged solution available: `MicrosoftEasyFix50410.msi`. You can download it at [microsoft.com](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/929852). Look for *Prefer IPv4 over IPv6 in prefix policies*.

If you want to prevent `ping` from using IPv6 at all, then use the `-4` option.

Comment: For future reference: **MicrosoftEasyFix50410.msi** can be found via article ID **929852**.