# Configuring Windows 10 to prefer IPV6

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, ipv6

I would like for Windows 10 to attempt connections to IPV6 before V4. Is there a setting I need to change in order to cause this preference?

Comment: By default, IPv6 should be the preferred connection type. Otherwise, see this previous [post](http://superuser.com/questions/436574/ipv4-vs-ipv6-priority-in-windows-7) and this Microsoft KB [article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/929852).

Comment: First verify with v6 ping that connection works `ping -6 google.com` if that fails there is connection/routing issues, but if it works but v6 still isn't preferred and `DisabledComponents` is unset, then what is the culprit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although an older question, I recently found a great answer and resources that you can download to use ipv6, ipv4, set precedence, etc.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/929852/guidance-for-configuring-ipv6-in-windows-for-advanced-users

I saw differences when tested with this free site:
http://test-ipv6.com/

Answer (score 1):

As CConard96 has mentioned above, since Windows Vista, the IPv6 is preferred on Windows OSes. The reason why the OS still use IPv4 to access the resources on net is because there is no available IPv6 path to the resource. One significant prove is that if you ping localhost on your Windows10, you will find that the reply is coming from ::1, which is the IPv6 loopback IP address.

Hope this helps.

Comment: First we check is that we have connection `ping -6 google.com` that works fine. Without `-6` we get a v4 reply, and `DisabledComponents` is not set. So even if this answer can be correct in some cases. it often isn't.