# HTTP over SSH tunnel on Windows

Tags: windows, networking, ssh, port-forwarding, tunnel

#### Situation:

Local windows machine runs a very simple HTTP web-server listening to `0.0.0.0:8080`.
Remote windows machine has [OpenSSH server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_overview) running and I have ssh-credentials but that's all I assume. It may not have internet, I do not have prior access or permission to reconfigure or install things, and/or it may only be capable of communicating through port 22.
I want the remote machine to access my local web-server and only it.

#### Plan:

I call the remote machine with `ssh myremote -R 8080:localhost:8080` opening a reverse tunnel and expect to reach my local webserver by issuing an HTTP, GET request, using powershell like so `Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://localhost:8080"` inside the session I have established.

#### Results:

```
Invoke-WebRequest : The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://localhost:8080"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

If I instead establish a tunnel to local port 22, `ssh myremote -R 8080:localhost:22`, I can successfully use the tunnel with an inner ssh back to my local machine, like `ssh localhost -p 8080`, assuming I have preconfigured access from the remote public key. With a local network, the remote can also directly call the webserver. That is not what I want to do, but it's clear that the tunnel is established correctly. Additionally, if the remote machine is the same as local, mapping perhaps `ssh localhost -R 8081:localhost:8080`, then calling `Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://localhost:8081"` has the exact same effect. Other methods, like using browsers to send http request has the same effect. Using forward tunneling from the remote (`-L` flag) has the same effect. Using any other means of listening to TCP traffic, Like `System.Net.Sockets.TCPListener` has the same effect (traffic never reaches it). Using PuTTY to establish equivalent tunnels has the same effect.

Single computer powershell procedure to replicate issue:

```
$port1 = 8080;
$port2 = 8081;
$Listener = [System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener]$port1;
$Listener.Start();
ssh localhost -R "${port2}:localhost:${port1}" powershell Invoke-Webrequest -Uri "http://localhost:$port2"
$Listener.Stop();
```

#### Questions:

Why does SSH succeed through the tunnel but anything else I try does not? How do I establish an HTTP or just a TCP connection back to my local server application through the reverse tunnel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Vista and newer resolves the loopback domain `localhost` to `::1` (IPv6) by default and the listening application must expect this. This was not the case for me with all of my software listening to `0.0.0.0` or `127.0.0.1` without support for both protocols.

#### Solution #1:

Use and configure a library or application that listens to both IPv4 and IPv6 sockets.

#### Solution #2:

Create the ssh tunnel using IPv4 explicitly either adding the `-4` flag or using `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`.

#### Solution #3:

Apply a prefix policy to the network interface to prioritize `127.0.0.1` or disable IPv6 preference completely.
Read [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/436944/1355119) for details on this solution.

If you have similar problems and this did not solve the issue, consider the address scope being listened to by both the ssh tunnel entry-point and the server. Don't listen to `localhost`, `::1` or `127.0.0.1` if these sockets must be reachable remotely. Specify the source IP range explicitly or use `::`, `0.0.0.0`, `*` or whatever the software documents as "any" source.